# Не отображаются картинки в форуме vBulletin® Version 3.8.4

Tags: vbulletin, форум, изображения, forum

Здравствуйте. имеется проблема... не отображается ни одна картинка в темах на форуме вот ссылка на одну из тем [sib-poker.ru](http://sib-poker.ru/showthread.php?t=41). Не могу понять в чем проблема... помогите!
Что ещё достаточно интересно, то, что в режиме "правка" и вообще в режиме создания темы, когда делаешь предварительный просмотр эти картинки отображаются!

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант это исправить в шаблоне, чтобы путь к картинкам указывался прямой, а не через скрипт. Сейчас там

```
<img src="watermark.php?src=http://newspoker.ru/files/gross_esf.jpg" border="0" alt="">
```

Comment: проблема в том что ни одно изображение не отображается в самом сообщении преобразованным bbcode'ОМ показываются только миниатюры. то есть фактически он находит картинку но в сообщении её отображать не хочет... вот пример чтоб понять http://sib-poker.ru/showthread.php?t=5